# how to get list of commits unique to a given branch

Tags: git

How would I get list of commits unique to a given branch?  This seems kind of close but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184378/how-to-get-only-unique-commits-in-git) captures commits from all branches and I'd like to limit it to a single branch I specify either through checking out that branch or passing it as an argument.

EDIT: the answer I was looking for is `git log master..foo`, which will generate a filtered list of commits.  I found that uniqueness, for my particular case, is defined by that which does not exist on master but the other branch being compared.

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: ah, thanks. There was supposed to be a link to another article. I'll edit the original post with the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're already aware that any given commit can be on one branch today, but three branches tomorrow, without that one commit changing in any way at all, what you want is simply:

```
git rev-list <branch> --not <all other branches>
```

where you fill in the branch names.  (If you meant that you want a script to compute the other branches, that's not very hard, depending on how robust a script you want.)

Of course, the moment anyone adds or deletes some branch names, or changes which commits are the tip commits of some existing branch names, that invalidates the output from the above, and you will have to re-run it.